# Create circular object from a 2d mesh

Tags: mesh, modifiers, extrude, 2d

1st of all i'm a beginner in blender or in modeling in general
so my apologizes if I use the wrong terms to explain my issue.

At some point I want to "transform" a side view 2d shape, in a circular object that rotate around an edge of it.
so having this 2d shape:
[image: side view shape]

that I want transform to a 3d shape with rotation around the edge in white (that is in 0,0):
[image: an anwful result]

To "achieve" that result above, I tried using some modifiers:

1. Solidify to get some thickness (of 2m here)
2. Array of 180 item + Empty with 2degree rotation in Z
3. Weld to try to enhance this aweful result

but the result is still bretty bad in the end and the generated mesh is pretty bad too (I'll export it in .stl)

So at this point I don't know what is the proper technic to achieve this kind of "circular extrusion".

In addition I'm trying to use modifiers because I didn't finished the initial shape yet and I really like the non-disruptive way.

any help would be welcome
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try a **Screw Modifier**. Just don't increase the "Screw" count (so it doesn't go "up"). You can increase the number of divisions from the modifier panel, and change the shape of the resulting object by transforming it in relation to it's origin (move it around in edit mode):

[image: Screw1]

[image: Screw2]

Comment: Slight nitpick but don't forget to check "Merge" if you are going 360° so the start and end points are merged. Might help if you want to bevel afterwards for instance.

Comment: that's great! it's doing exactlty what I needed, with a smooth result. btw I noticed there is a rendering difference if the initial 2d shape is filled with a face or not.